# FileNotFoundException for WebMvcConfigurerAdapter dependency for spring-core-6.0.2 not found after Spring Boot 3 upgrade

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have upgraded a project that I am working on from Spring Boot 2.7.7 to 3.0.0. There were some classes in the project that depended on the deprecated WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class, but I have removed the dependency and use the replacement WebMvcConfigurer interface.

Version info

Java - 17

Springframework - 6.0.2

Spring Boot - 3.0.0

Spring Cloud - 2022.0.0

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.app.Application]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:179) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:283) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:745) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at com.app.Application.main(Application.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:211) ~[spring-core-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54) ~[spring-core-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:48) ~[spring-core-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:611) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:924) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:335) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:244) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:244) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

I am unsure how to proceed or why this exception is being thrown. I have searched for any references to WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in the project, and there are none.

Comment: It looks like you have a `@Configuration` class in your application or one of its dependencies that is referencing `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. You could use the debugger and a breakpoint to suspend the application when `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class` cannot be found. When the app is suspended look at the class that `ConfigurationClassParser` is processing to identify the cause.